# Save current page from firefox add-on

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm need a way to save the current page (including, images, CSS, etc.) from an add-on.

Of course I found the saveDocument() function in the SDK but I was not able to make it work.

- from add-on script, I do not have access to actual DOM content
- from content script, I do not have access to SDK function 'saveDocument()'

I miss something, I would be very happy if someone could help me.

Best regards,

Fred

Comment: Could you provide a link to the saveDocument function documentation?

Comment: What's wrong with goging to the menu bar (press `Alt`) if it's hidden and then `File` > `Save Page As` and then for `File Type` pick `Webpage, complete`?

Comment: Are you trying to save the page with the changes that javascript made to the page? Try this add-on: [Save Back to File from DOM](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/save-back-to-file-from-dom/?src=search)

Comment: the saveDocment function documentation I used may be found there :https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Miscellaneous

Comment: Noitidart: JS modified content is definitevly a thema, I will look at it later since I tend to start with more simple use-cases. Thanks very much for the link.

Comment: The reason why I try to re-implement "Save As Page menu" is because I want to add functionalities to it : tagging, selected text, etc. In order to archive and classify content.

Comment: Since mozdev.org is back online, I will look at existing addon now (like maf).

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

here's one way to access the DOM document from addon script.

```js
var winutil = require('sdk/window/utils');
function findDocument(predicate){
    // searching in focused window only
    // you can also get all windows with winutil.windows('navigator:browser')
    var win = winutil.getMostRecentBrowserWindow();
    var gBrowser = win.gBrowser;
    // traverse tabs of focused window
    for (var i=0, l=gBrowser.browsers.length; i<l; i++)
    {   
        var br = gBrowser.getBrowserAtIndex(i);
        var doc = br.contentDocument;
        if (predicate(doc))
            return doc;
    }   
}
// and this is probably how you would save (not tested)
var {Cc, Ci} = require('chrome');
var wbp = Cc["@mozilla.org/embedding/browser/nsWebBrowserPersist;1"]
    .createInstance(Ci.nsIWebBrowserPersist);
var doc = findDocument(/* whatever */);
if (doc)
    wbp.saveDocument(doc, /* figure out other args */);
```